# How to assign a value to value of a variable in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
X=email
Y=5
$X = Y
```

Value of X i.e, email = Y
I want to assign Y value to value of X I.e, email

Comment: what do you want to do explain it clearly with some example and python don't support `$X` and what do you mean by `$X`

Comment: I want to assign Y value to value of X I.e, email. At final email=5

Comment: first you can't use not defined variables `X = email` in this you can't use this

Comment: `email` is string or variable

Answer (score 0):

To assign variables, python does not use `$`, it is as simple as

```py
X = Y
```

As an additional note, if you wanted `X` to be set to the text `email`, use quotes around it, like so:

```py
X = "email"
```

Comment: Thanks for replay sir. I want to assign Y value to value of X I.e, email. How I can achieve that? Here x value is keep on

Comment: Do you mean the text "email" or a variable. If you mean text, use `X = "email"`. If you mean a variable, use `X = email`.

Comment: email is a text assigned to X. I want assign Y value to value of X I.e, email

Comment: I want to make email as a variable after assigning  Y value

Comment: Are you saying that you want to make a new variable called email? If so, just flip it around, so it is `email = Y`

Comment: Here X value will keep on change at present email.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please use full, grammatically correct sentences, it will make it easier for me to help you.

Comment: In shell script: X='email'; Y=5; ${X}=Y; echo $email prints 5. How can I achieve same in python